# Cannot make Conference Call using Skype on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, skype

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. With Skype Linux version 4.3.0.37 when I try a conference call, my friends can hear me, but there is no video. They receive a notification saying I need to upgrade Skype. There is no problem for a simple video call. Both audio and video work perfectly. I have downloaded Skype from http://www.skype.com/. The Skype website don't have any recent updates for Linux distributions.

Any help on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Enable the Ubuntu Partner repository in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and uncomment the line

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
```

Remove skype

```
sudo apt-get remove skype
```

Then install skype again

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall skype
```